# Compare with hex

Tags: vimscript

How to compare with hex? Wanted to test I had it right. At first I thought

```
let a = 13

if a == "\x0d"  | echo "Match 13" | else | echo "Not 13" |  endif " => Not 13
```

Then I went for

```
if a =~ '\%x0d' | echo "Match 13" | else | echo "Not 13" |  endif " => Not 13
```

As that did not work I started down a hole testing various:

```
'\x0d', '\%x0d', "\%x0d", '\\x0d', "\\x0d", "\\%x0d", '\xd', '\%xd', "\xd", "\%xd" ...
```

All with test by:

```
==, =~, =~#, =~?, ==#, ==?
```

Also tested with:

```
if str2nr('13')
if a+0
```

Always with same result "Not 13"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you're looking for is `0x0d`, which is a Number that evaluates to the hexadecimal value equivalent to 13.

```
if a == 0x0d  | echo "Match 13" | else | echo "Not 13" |  endif
" => Match 13
```

The other expressions you used don't really work because they're strings and in some of them you're using the syntax to match hexadecimal characters in patterns, which won't work either...

You can get from character `"\x0d"` to the number 13 with `char2nr()`:

```
:echo char2nr("\x0d")
" => 13
```

(Note that the result is a Number, not a string.)

Conversely, you can use `nr2char()` to convert the 13 in `a` to the character with that ASCII code:

```
if nr2char(a) == "\x0d"  | echo "Match 13" | else | echo "Not 13" |  endif
" => Match 13
```